# Are these planes always perpendicular?

Tags: geometry

> The picture shows a pyramid (not necessarily a right pyramid).
> [image: 1]
>
> $V$ is the apex of the pyramid , and $ABCD$ is it's base.
>
> Let $\alpha$ be the plane $AVC$ and $\beta$ the plane $BVD$.
>
> True or false: If $ABCD$ is a square, then $\alpha$ is always perpendicular to $\beta$.
>
> Prove it (using only euclidian geometry; vectors/coordinates are not allowed).

**My thought process so far:**

I first thought since $ABCD$ is a square, then $AC$ is perpendicular to $BD$. But this doesn't guarantee $\alpha$ is perpendicular to $\beta$. There's no theorem saying that if a line in a plane is perpendicular to a line in another plane, then the planes are perpendicular.

If $V$ were guaranteed to be straight over the center of $ABCD$, then it would be easy to prove the proposition is true. The intersection line between $\alpha$ and $\beta$ would be perpendicular to the base and, since $AC$ is perpendicular to $BD$, the planes would be perpendicular to each other by definition of angle between planes.

I think I'm stuck because the pyramid could be oblique.

Comment: How far have you gotten with it?

Comment: "True or False":) have you worked on this exercise ?

Comment: I thought since ABCD is a square, then AC is perpendicular to BD. But this doesn't guarantee $\alpha$ is perpendicular to $\beta$. There's no theorem saying that if a line in a plane is perpendicular to a line in another plane, then the planes are perpendicular. So I'm stuck.

Comment: Exactly how do you mean '(not necessarily a *right* pyramid)'? So, is $V$ guaranteed to be straight over the center of the square $ABCD$?

Comment: No, it's not guaranteed. If it were, it would be easy to prove the proposition is true. The intersection between $\alpha$ and $\beta$ would be a line perpendicular to the base and, since AC is perpendicular to BD, the planes would be perpendicular to each other by definition. I'm stuck because the pyramid could be oblique.

Comment: When you get stuck trying to prove something is true, the alternate strategy is to try to prove that it is false by constructing a counterexample.

Comment: Yes, I agree. But I've no idea how to construct such counterexample. My intuition says the planes are always perpendicular. I tried imagining the apex moving in many directions, approaching the base, etc., and seeing if the planes stop being perpendicular in my mind. But I don't have the best spatial intelligence.

Comment: Put $V$ directly above $BC$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let point $E$ be the intersection point of the diagonals $AC$ and $BD$ of the square base $ABCD$. Through points $B$ and $C$ draw lines $b$ and $c$ parallel to the line $EV$. Take the point $F$ on line $b$ such that $EF$ is perpendicular to $b$. Furthermore, take the point $G$ on line $c$ such that $EG$ is perpendicular to $c$. Since by construction $EV \, || \, b \, || \, c$, the segments $EF$ and $EG$ are perpendicular to $EV$, which means that the whole plane $(EFG)$ is perpendicular to $EV$ and therefore the angle between the planes $(BVD) = (EVB)$ and $(AVC) = (EVC)$   is the angle $\angle \, FEG$.

Since $EV \, || \, b \, || \, c$ and $EV$ is perpendicular to the plane $(EFG)$, the lines $b$ and $c$ are also perpendicular to $(EFG)$ and in particular $b$ and $c$ are perpendicular to the segment $FG$, i.e. $\angle \, BFG = \angle \, CGF = 90^{\circ}$.

Since the triangle $\Delta\, BCE$ is right-angle isosceles, $EB = EC = a$ and $BC = \sqrt{2}\, a$. By construction, $\angle \, EFB = 90^{\circ}$, so if we denote $\angle \, BEF = \alpha$, for right-angled triangle $\Delta\, BEF$
$$EF = a\,\cos(\alpha) \, \text{ and } \, BF = a\, \sin(\alpha)$$
If we denote $\angle \, CEG = \beta$, absolutely analogous arguments yield
$$EG = a\,\cos(\beta) \, \text{ and } \, CG = a\, \sin(\beta)$$
If w look at the quad $BCGF$, it is a trapezoid ($EF = b \, || \, c = CG$) with $FG$ perpendicular to $BF$ and $CG$, by Pythgoras' theorem
$$FG^2 = BC^2 - (BF - CG)^2 = 2a^2 - \big(a\sin(\alpha) - a\sin(\beta)\big)^2$$

Finally, if we look at the triangle $\Delta \, EFG$ we know that
$$EF = a\cos(\alpha) \,\, \, EG = a\cos(\beta) \,\,\, \text{ and } \,\,\, FG^2 = 2a^2 - \big(a\sin(\alpha) - a\sin(\beta)\big)^2$$ By Pythagoras' theorem (full version) $\Delta EFG = 90^{\circ}$ if and only if
$$EF^2 + EG^2 - FG^2 = 0$$
So let's write this down:
$$a^2\cos^2(\alpha) + a^2\cos^2(\beta) - 2a^2 +  \big(a\sin(\alpha) - a\sin(\beta)\big)^2 = 0$$
Expand and simplify
$$a^2\cos^2(\alpha) + a^2\cos^2(\beta) - 2a^2 +  a^2\sin^2(\alpha) + a^2\sin^2(\beta) - 2\,a^2 \sin(\alpha)\sin(\beta) = 0$$ which simplifies to
$$\sin(\alpha)\sin(\beta) = 0$$
which is possible only when $\alpha = 0$ or $\beta = 0$, when the angles are between $0$ and $90^{\circ}$.
So, this shows that the two planes $(AVC)$ and $(BVC)$ are perpendicular if and only if
$$\angle \, BEF = 0 \,\, \text{ or } \,\, \angle \, CEG = 0$$
which means that the two planes $(AVC)$ and $(BVC)$ are perpendicular if and only if $EV$ is perpendicular to the diagonal $BD$, or $EV$ is perpendicular to the diagonal $AC$,  or $EV$ is perpendicular to both, so to the whole base plane $ABCD$. This can also be reformulated as follows:
The two planes $(AVC)$ and $(BVC)$ are perpendicular if and only if $VA = VC$, or $VB = VD$, or $VA = VB = VC = VD$.

Comment: As a comment, $EV$ is perpendicular to $BD$ iff $V's$ projection on the base is along $AC$. So our answers match.

Comment: @Kaind Yes, it is because $EV \perp BD$ if and only if $EV$ is a perpendicular bisector of $BD$ which means that triangle $\Delta \, BDV$ is isosocelles, i.e. $VB =VD$.

Answer (score 3):

Let's just use 3D coordinates and see what happens.

WLOG, let $V = (x_0,y_0,z_0)$ s.t. $z_0 > 0$,
and let $A = (-1,0,0), B = (0,-1,0), C = (1,0,0) , D = (0,1,0)$.

The equation of plane $AVC$ is:
$\begin{bmatrix}
    x       & y & z  & 1 \\
    -1       & 0 & 0  & 1 \\
     1       & 0 & 0  & 1 \\                                                   
     x_0      & y_0 & z_0  & 1
\end{bmatrix} = 0$

Hence it's normal is along the vector $(0, -2z_0, 2y_0)$.

The equation of plane $BVD$ is:
$\begin{bmatrix}
    x       & y & z  & 1 \\
    0       & -1 & 0  & 1 \\
     0       & 1 & 0  & 1 \\                                                   
     x_0      & y_0 & z_0  & 1
\end{bmatrix} = 0$

Hence it's normal is along the vector $(2z_0, 0, -2x_0)$.

Hence the dot product of the two normals is $0$ iff $x_0y_0 = 0$.

So **no**, in general. Also we can see that if the base is a square, then those planes are perpendicular only when the apex's projection lies on one of the diagonals of the square.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This proves that the proposition is false. But I'm trying to find a proof that don't use algebra. Euclidian geometry postulates and theorems only. I'm going to edit the post.

Comment: Well my final statement shows how to construct a counterexample. So a counterexample would be when $V$'s projection on the base is not on any diagonal.

Comment: So, if algebra *were* allowed, let $\vec{AB}=2\mathbf{i},\vec{BC}=\mathbf{j},$ and $\vec{DV}=\mathbf{i}+\mathbf{k},$ then use cross product to find a normal of each of the two required planes, then show that the dot product of these two normals is nonzero (it in fact equals $4$).

Comment: @Ryan: That's what I've done above. Just used cartesian coordinates instead of vectors.

Comment: Yes, I was explicating your final sentence.

Comment: When I say algebra, I'm including analytic geometry (vectors). Euclidian postulates and theorems only. I'm trying to do the proof by myself, but it's easier said than done.

Answer (score -1):

The planes are not always perpendicular.

Imagine a point $E$, halfway between $A$ and $B$. The point $V$ can relocate anywhere along the line from $V$ to $E$ and, provided that it is not coincident with $E$, the volume would still be a pyramid with a square base.

Now take the extreme case where $V$ is very, very close to $E$, but not exactly at $E$. To convey the idea graphically, imagine the distance between $V$ and $E$ is the width of an atom... Technically, we still have a square-based pyramid, but for practical purposes it's a flat surface, like a sheet of paper.

In this scenario, the planes you are asking about, $AVC$ and $BVD$, will also lie on this sheet of paper, and would therefore be parallel (or very nearly so).

Comment: I don't see why AVC e BVD would be parallel. Indeed, they are not, since V is a common point between them. Either way, this is not a mathematical proof.